# Is the cumulative incidence function just an inverted Kaplan-Meier survival curve?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

Is CIF just an inverted Kaplan-Meier survival curve, and nothing more?

Comment: Check out this paper here for some useful reading on the topic: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2410013/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about the cumulative incidence function that arises from a Kaplan-Meier estimator, then it's just $1 - S(t)$ where $t$ is time. In R:

```
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
plot(fit) # the standard survival curve
plot(fit, fun="event") # the cumulative incidence curve
```

**But**, CIF is more commonly used in other contexts, for example in competing risk analysis using cause-specific Cox regression. There, the CIF is *not necessarily* equal to $1-S(t)$ because it takes into account the competing risk, estimating the risk of an event happening given survival up to time $t$ and also that a competing risk hasn't occurred up to time $t$.

Comment: GREAT THANKS! COULD I CALL (IN THE ARTICLE, IN WHICH I ANALYZE GROUP OF PATIENTS) CIF AS A "CUMULATIVE FREQUENCY OF RISK" (ASSOCIATED WITH SOME FACTOR) OR SIMPLER: "CUMULATIVE RISK"?

Comment: If you're referring to the no-competing risk scenario, then I'd just call it cumulative risk.